# Sql injection with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Does the following expose a Sql Injection attack vector? If it does how do I prevent it?

```
@bookId = '1234;' + 'Drop table Books;'
Select * from Books where bookId = @bookId
```

Won't it be executed like so ? :

```
Select * from Books where bookId = 1234; Drop table Books;
```

Comment: What happens when you run that command?

Comment: By not passing unfiltered user input into your database layer. There's no useful way to answer this question since you've only tagged it "sql". Your users can't supply input directly into your database server. "SQL Injection" doesn't make any sense at this level.

Comment: @meagar Yes I know I implyed a little too much here. But you get the point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not. That's not how parameterization works. Parameterization is not string concatenation.

This code will try to find a book whose id is `1234;Drop table Books;`. Which will fail in type cast if `bookId` is an `integer`.

You are safe.

Comment: So the compiler won't simply replace the `@Parameter` part with it's value ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - This isn't the compiler at work here. It is the database driver - it will escape the parameters and do other things.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - Just a word of caution - using parameters doesn't automatically make your SQL safe from injection. If you build up SQL inside a stored procedure and are using passed in parameters, you can still be vulnerable. If you want an in-depth article on the subject, read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: @Oded Ok thanks I'll look into it ! I've never worked in an environment where it was important to check for injections so I want to take good habits.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find this useful: http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs142/lectures/16-sql-inj.pdf